# How do I correctly wire this lighted switch to provide power down the line?

Tags: electrical, switch

I've gotten in over my head!

I just the Leviton lighted switches like the one in the pic shown for our bathrooms. There's just something so nice about the small light it gives off when it's the middle of the night!

That said, it's not fully working! :) I've been able to figure out witch wire is HOT from the breaker box and I also know which wire is the load out to the lights this switch controls.

There's a third line that WHEN I hook up to the screw that's on a side by itself DOES power up the light in the switch. But, there is another room of lights down past this switch that will NOT work when I'm wired up this way.

I have found that if a bypass the single side screw and patch to the hot line coming in, the other bathroom lights up just fine!

I am guessing that I don't have netural connected correctly, so I am not making a complete circut without the other room. But, it's beyond me at this point!

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: AAAAANNNNDDDD... I think I know what might be wrong! This is a LOAD ON switch, not a night light! :)

Comment: Yeah, so it is a 1201-PLC and believe it or not, yeah I googled a bit and figured it out. These are all hot side lines. This box has 3 full romex'es in. 1 for line, 1 to load and 1 to the next room. I wired the switch backwards thinking it was a lighted with load off style. But, it's a lighted with load on. So, I need a different switch. Neutral lines are still in the box, pigtailed together. BTW, your tone is judgemental and not appriecated. I am sure it feels great to be an expert, but don't look down because you won't always be just that!

Comment: Sorry I posted this earlier then deleted it to add a bit, so it's out of sequence. This appears to be a Leviton 1201-PLC.  Honestly this installation looks like it's way over your head given its complexities.  If you're using a black neutral there's probably a dozen other things also being done incorrectly.  May be time to get a book on electrical and read it through; you need a well rounded primer, which is not what Google is.

Comment: And I'm not judging, I want you to be successful at DIY electrical..  But it's actually dangerous to stretch your skills; I'm saying rather than learn bits one at a time from Google, which will give you swiss cheese knowledge, get them wholesale from a book so you have a well-rounded primer of all the stuff you need to do.  The problem is Google only answers questions; you need the primer to know what questions to ask. I'm sorry if that rubs  your personality the wrong way, but I'm an experienced educator, it's good advice, and it's NOT an insult.

Comment: Your missing context... I wired in the switch late last night after rewiring the bathroom. I came into work and posted this question hoping not for a lecture, but a quick catch by someone. Within 5 minutes of posting this I had figured out I was on 3 hot lines and needed to bring in the neutral.  Don't they say those who can't do, teach? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for the neutral to attach to it, there is a big bunch of neutrals in the back. Add a short white wire to that wirenut and connect that to the silver screw.

To provide power to the next lights you need to take a short black wire and pigtail that along with the black to the next load and the black from the breaker. Then use the short black wire to connect to the switch.

Comment: Now THIS is the right answer! It is a lack of neutral. I just wired the switch in last night and killed power to the other bathroom this morning. I hadn't yet had time to think it all out.